# Numerically solve differential equation with square terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I would like to solve the following differential equation numerically:

$$(1 + (y')^2) (y - c) - y'  x = 0$$
where $y$ is a function of $x$, and $y(0) = a$ and $y'(0) = b$.

I was looking into Runge Kutta methods but it requires the equation to be in the following format:

$$y' = f(x, y)$$

If I can achieve this, then it's straightforward to solve it with Runge-Kutta. But I don't see how it's possible to get it into this format.

Comment: Solve the quadratic given for $y'$ then continue as you have explained.

Comment: @Nimyz: What are the values of $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for the answer! So it means there are two different equations that satisfy my differential equation. This makes sense because I ended up with this equation from the Euler-Lagrange condition of calculus of variations. The solution to this equation will make my functional stationary so one of them will probably maximize and one of them will minimize my functional.

Comment: @Moo a, b and c are constants specific to the problem I am solving, their value is not so important.

Comment: Perhaps @Moo is hinting at the idea that which branch of the square root you take might depend on $a$ and $b$ (as well it might!)

Comment: Yes it might depend on it. I will solve the differential equation of both branches then, and check which one minimizes my functional. This is the solution I need. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Does this mean then that there exist differential equations which cannot be solved numerically? Because this technique relies on first analytically solving the equation for $y'$ which is not possible in general if it contains polynomial terms of degree higher than 4.

Comment: It means that there are DE that cannot be solved by first assuming that you can write down a function $f$ with $y' = f(x, y)$. There are plenty of techniques that don't assume this. But if you write that $F(y') = 0$ for some 5-th degree polyonomial $F$ (whose coefficients might depend on $x$, etc.), then you haven't really specified $y'$ in general, because there might be up to five different values that are roots of the polynomial, so it's not completely clear to me what "solving" means in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
0 &= (1 + (y')^2)  (y - c) - y'  x \\
0 &= (y-c) + (y')^2  (y - c) - y'  x \\
0 &= (y')^2(y - c)  - y'  x + (y - c)  \\
0 &= (y-c) \left[ (y')^2  - y'  \frac{x}{y-c} + \left( \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right)^2 - \left( \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right)^2 \right]+ (y - c)   \\
0 &= (y-c) \left[y' - \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right]^2 - (y-c)\frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}+  (y-c)   \\
0 &= (y-c) \left( \left[y' - \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right]^2 - \frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}+  1  \right) \\
\end{align}
At this point, we can say that either $y-c$ is zero, or the other term is zero; the first case is pretty simple (and is a valid solution!); the second gives us

\begin{align}
0 &=  \left[y' - \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right]^2 - \frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}+  1  \\
 \frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}-  1 &=  \left[y' - \frac{x}{2(y-c)}\right]^2   \\
\pm \sqrt{ \frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}-  1} &=  y' - \frac{x}{2(y-c)}   \\
 \frac{x}{2(y-c)}  \pm \sqrt{ \frac{x^2}{4(y-c)^2}-  1} &=  y'    \\
\end{align}
which expresses $y'$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ as required. Near $x = 0$, you'll have to choose a particular branch of the square root, however. That's hardly surprising, given that $y'^2$ appears in the original equation.

Comment: Thanks, this is line with wat @PeterForeman said above. From the nature of my problem I know that $y(x) = c$ is not a valid solution so I can proceed with solving the 2 differential equations corresponding with the 2 branches of the square root.